# How do i write this shorter with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me.
I want to write this code better and shorter.
So how do I write this jQuery code snippet shorter and better?

```
$("#empty_trash").click(function() {
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="underbukser"></li>');
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="underbukser"></li>');
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="underbukser"></li>');
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="underbukser"></li>');
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="underbukser"></li>');
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="underbukser"></li>');
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="underbukser"></li>');
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="underbukser"></li>');
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="underbukser"></li>');
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="underbukser"></li>');
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="t-shirt"></li>');
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="t-shirt"></li>');
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="t-shirt"></li>');
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="t-shirt"></li>');
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="t-shirt"></li>');
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="t-shirt"></li>');
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="t-shirt"></li>');
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="t-shirt"></li>');
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="t-shirt"></li>');
    $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="t-shirt"></li>');
});
```

Comment: You might want to accept an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps with a loop?

```
$("#empty_trash").click(function() {
    var elem = $('.wardopeskab ul');

    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        elem.prepend('<li class="underbukser"></li>');
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        elem.prepend('<li class="t-shirt"></li>');
    }
});
```

Preferably you wouldn't use the magic numbers; 10 should have a name of some sort. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, so I'm not sure what it would be named.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake! Deleted my answer since pointless. +1

Answer (score 4):

A little raw JavaScript power:

```
$('.wardopeskab ul')
    .prepend(
        new Array(11).join('<li class="underbukser">underbukser</li>') +
        new Array(11).join('<li class="t-shirt">t-shirt</li>')
    );
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8yEhE/5/

Note: The number `11` in `new Array(11)` is 1 more than the times it will be written out.

Comment: No `for` loops and one `append`.

Answer (score -1):

Use loops, for loops, while loops, etc:

```
$("#empty_trash").click(function () {
    while ( /* Loop Condition Here */ ) {

        $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="underbukser"></li>');

    }
    while ( /* Loop Condition Here */ ) {

        $('.wardopeskab ul').prepend('<li class="t-shirt"></li>');

    }

});
```